# MarkAsTouched not effect on radio button (not showing radio buttons red) in angular 4

Tags: angular

MarkAsTouched not effect on radio button (not showing radio buttons red) in angular 4, other textbox and dropdown works fine only radio button is not showing red.

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: finally i found my answer. just put this code in .scss file mat-radio-group.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
    color:red;
}